Not getting search results if Views: Exposed Filter search text has html entities
Summary:
Installed Fresh Drupal 10.2.4
No other custom codes or contrib modules.
Added two contents for "Article" content type.

Created a view with page.

Format: Fields

Fields: Title and Body fields added.

Filter criteria:

Published = yes
Content type ="Article"
Added "Body" field and exposed it. Operator selected as "contains".


Apply and saved the view.


Issue:
Example text: I am learning Drupal backend & frontend.

Search some text without "&" : Example: I am learning  => getting
results.

Search some text with "&": Example: I am learning Drupal backend &
=> getting results.

Search some text with "&": Example: I am learning Drupal backend &
front => not getting results.


Added screenshot for reference:

Any guidance, to get a working solution for my issue please?

Does it matter at all that it’s a combined fields filter?

Yes, whatever steps I followed in D10, I have added, and with combined field filter, I need to achieve this.

My question means: Does this also happen for ordinary field filters too?

Hi @mona, Yes, I tried adding body filed in the filter criteria, exposed it, selected operator as "contains", and when I search without "&", it works, but not working with adding "& sometext", so means, its not about combine field filter, normal search with "&", its not working

Update this Question.

Updated my question @mona

I’m voting to close this question because it appeared as a bug report at https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3465946. We can answer questions here but not resolve bug reports.

I have managed by using html_entity_decode() for my requirement.
